# Structuring a list of objects in python for vectorization: Can a list of structures(objects) be vectorized, or are explicit arrays required

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Energy calculations in molecular simulation are inherently full of "for" loops. Traditionally coordinates for each atom/molecule were stored in arrays. arrays are fairly straightforward to vectorize, but structures are nice to code with. Treating molecules as individual objects, each with their own coordinates, and other properties, is very convenient and much clearer as far as book-keeping goes.

## I am using Python version 3.6

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to vectorize calculations when I am using an array of objects... it seems that a for loop cannot be avoided. Is it necessary for me to use arrays in order to take advantage of numpy and vectorize my code?

Here is a python example which utilizes arrays (line 121 of the code), and shows a fast (numpy) and slow ( 'normal') python energy calculation.

https://github.com/Allen-Tildesley/examples/blob/master/python_examples/mc_lj_module.py

The calculation is much faster using the numpy accelerated method because it is vectorized.

How would I vectorize an energy calculation if I was not using arrays, but an array of objects, each with their own coordinates? This seems to necessitate using the slower for loop.

## Here is a simple example code with a working slow version of the for loop, and an attempted vectorization that doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
import time

class Mol:  
    num = 0    
    def __init__(self, r):
        Mol.num += 1
        self.r       = np.empty((3),dtype=np.float_)
        self.r[0]     = r[0]
        self.r[1]     = r[1] 
        self.r[2]     = r[2]
    """ Alot more useful things go in here in practice"""

################################################
#                                              #
#               Main Program                   #
#                                              #
################################################
L = 5.0            # Length of simulation box (arbitrary)
r_cut_box_sq = L/2 # arbitrary cutoff - required
mol_list=[]
nmol = 1000    # number of molecules
part = 1    # arbitrary molecule to interact with rest of molecules

""" make 1000 molecules (1 atom per molecule), give random coordinates """
for i in range(nmol):
    r = np.random.rand(3) * L
    mol_list.append( Mol( r ) )

energy = 0.0

start = time.time()
################################################
#                                              #
#   Slow but functioning loop                  #
#                                              #
################################################
for i in range(nmol):
    if i == part:
        continue

    rij = mol_list[part].r - mol_list[i].r
    rij = rij - np.rint(rij/L)*L                # apply periodic boundary conditions
    rij_sq = np.sum(rij**2)  # Squared separations

    in_range = rij_sq < r_cut_box_sq                
    sr2      = np.where ( in_range, 1.0 / rij_sq, 0.0 )
    sr6  = sr2 ** 3
    sr12 = sr6 ** 2
    energy  += sr12 - sr6                    

end = time.time()
print('slow: ', end-start)
print('energy: ', energy)

start = time.time()
################################################
#                                              #
#   Failed vectorization attempt               #
#                                              #
################################################


    """ The next line is my problem, how do I vectorize this so I can avoid the for loop all together?
Leads to error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'r' """

""" I also must add in that part cannot interact with itself in mol_list"""
rij = mol_list[part].r - mol_list[:].r
rij = rij - np.rint(rij/L)*L                # apply periodic boundary conditions
rij_sq = np.sum(rij**2) 

in_range = rij_sq < r_cut_box_sq
sr2      = np.where ( in_range, 1.0 / rij_sq, 0.0 )
sr6  = sr2 ** 3
sr12 = sr6 ** 2
energy  = sr12 - sr6                    

energy = sum(energy)
end = time.time()
print('faster??: ', end-start)
print('energy: ', energy)
```

## Lastly

Would any possible solutions be affected if inside the energy calculation, it was necessary to loop over each atom in each molecule where their is now more than 1 atom per molecule, and not all molecules have the same number of atoms, thus having a double for loop for molecule-molecule interactions rather than the simple pair-pair interactions currently employed.

Comment: What specific calculations do you seek to vectorize

Comment: The energy calculation in the last for loop. energy is the sum of all pair interactions... I would like to calculate all pair interactions simultaneously, and then sum them up at the end rather than looping through all pair interactions

Comment: Could you make your example only include the part you seek to vectorize...This is not useful for future users at all. It's quite possible that your question is a duplicate disguised as a new problem.

Comment: The first for loop works and gives a baseline for any working vectorization to be compared with. It would not make sense not have a piece of code to test against. Everything is clearly labelled.

Comment: The fastest calculations in `numpy` are those that use compiled code, working with numerical `dtypes` - elementwise and matrix multiplications, the various `ufunc`, and indexing that avoids copies.  `numba` and `cython` can be used to compile more iterative calculations.  But as a general rule these tools don't play well with object oriented  code.  Arrays of objects require the same sort of iteration as lists of objects (and are a bit slower).  And `cython` can't reduce the calculations to pure C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of the itertools library might be the way forward here. Suppose you wrap the energy calculation of a pair of molecules in a function:

```
def calc_pairwise_energy((mol_a,mol_b)):
    # function takes a 2 item tuple of molecules
    # energy calculating code here
    return pairwise_energy
```

Then you can use itertools.combinations to get all the pairs of molecules and python's built in list comprehensions (the code inside [ ] on the last line below):

```
from itertools import combinations
pairs = combinations(mol_list,2)
energy = sum( [calc_pairwise_energy(pair) for pair in pairs] )
```

I've come back to this answer as I realised I hadn't properly answered your question. With what I've already posted the pairwise energy calculation function looked like this (I've made a few optimisations to your code):

```
def calc_pairwise_energy(molecules):
    rij = molecules[0].r - molecules[1].r
    rij = rij - np.rint(rij/L)*L
    rij_sq = np.sum(rij**2)  # Squared separations
    if rij_sq < r_cut_box_sq:
        return (rij_sq ** -6) - (rij_sq ** - 3)
    else:
        return 0.0
```

Whereas a vectorised implementation that does all the pairwise calculations in a single call might look like this:

```
def calc_all_energies(molecules):
    energy = 0
    for i in range(len(molecules)-1):
        mol_a = molecules[i]
        other_mols = molecules[i+1:]
        coords = np.array([mol.r for mol in other_mols])
        rijs = coords - mol_a.r
        # np.apply_along_axis replaced as per @hpaulj's  comment (see below)
        #rijs = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x - np.rint(x/L)*L,0,rijs)
        rijs = rijs - np.rint(rijs/L)*L
        rijs_sq = np.sum(rijs**2,axis=1)
        rijs_in_range= rijs_sq[rijs_sq < r_cut_box_sq]
        energy += sum(rijs_in_range ** -6 - rijs_in_range ** -3)
    return energy
```

This is much faster but there is still plenty to optimise here.

Comment: @T Burgis I consistently get that the second method, the vectorized method (calc_all_energies), is a little over 10x faster! If you have been playing with it more and have found more optimizations, please let me know.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` just iterates over the other dimensions of the input array.  It's a convenience function, but not a true 'vectorization'.

Comment: @hpaulj - I guess you could do it vectorised in two steps and it would probably be faster. First generate a vector of np.rint(x/L)*L and then substract it from the rijs vector?

Comment: @hpaulj - I had a look and the `apply_along_axis` can be replaced by `rijs = rijs - np.rint(rijs/L)*L`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate energies with coordinates as inputs, I'm assuming you're looking for pair-wise distances. For this, you should look into the SciPy library. Specifically, I would look at `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html).